# JavaScript: Access between two functions defined in global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope, global

can anyone explain the following to me. I have two JavaScript functions defined in global scope as follows:

```
    var foo = function () {
        var that = this;

        that.toString = function () { return "foobar" };

        return that;
    }();

    alert(foo.toString());

    var foo2 = function (foo) {
        var that;

        that = $.extend(true, {}, foo);

        return that;
    }();
```

Alerting foo.toString() works as I would expect as foo is assigned the result of invoking the function. However I would have expected foo2 to have access to foo.  Yet inside foo2 foo is undefined.  Can anyone help?

Many Thanks,
Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a function which accepts an argument called *foo*.  This local variable will override the global variable of the same name.  If you don't pass in anything for this argument, the local *foo* is automatically set to *undefined*.  You can either remove the argument or pass the global *foo*.

```
var foo2 = function (foo) {
    var that;

    that = $.extend(true, {}, foo); // foo is from the local scope

    return that;
}(foo); // Pass in foo
```

Or

```
var foo2 = function () { // remove the argument
    var that;

    that = $.extend(true, {}, foo); // foo is from the global scope

    return that;
}();
```

Comment: Andy, in general is there a preference between the two options you present?

Comment: @Godders: you would usually opt for using the outer scope variable, unless there's a chance the variable could be changed by the outer scope before it's used in the inner scope, in a timer callback function.  Put simply, use the second option if you're not accessing the variable from a timer function or AJAX *onreadystatechange* event handler.

Comment: @Godders: just to add for completeness' sake: in functions where speed optimization is important, you can better use the first variant: accessing local variables is generally (a tiny bit) faster than accessing global variables. That said, with this closure thing I'm not so sure it is.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is undefined in `foo2` because you're defining a local `foo` as a parameter:

```
var foo2 = function (foo) { ...
```

and you're then calling `foo2` with no arguments:

```
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making `foo2` create another variable called `foo` inside its scope, with a value of `undefined`. If you want access `foo`, use:

```
var foo2 = function (foo) {
  //code
}(foo);
```

or access it from the window object:

```
window.foo
```